# Display content from other pages on wordpress home page

Tags: wordpress

I want to display the content from different pages on my wordpress home page in a way that it displays an image, page heading and some content with the link to that page. Any help is appreciated. If there is any plugin available please let me know that. Sorry to all the pros, i am, just a beginner in wordpress. I have attached an image too of what i am, looking for.

Thanks and Regards.

[image: image for the problem]

Comment: Are these specific pages you want to display, or pages from a custom post type or associated to a specific category or tag?

Comment: Thanks @fostertime for your reply. Actually these are going to be pages that we add from wordpress. all the four would be the pages here.

Comment: So there are 4 pages? No more, no less? Are there other pages you've added that you don't want on the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use post instead of pages and than display those posts in you home page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the plugin Advanced Custom Fields on one page or post, and then pulling them onto other pages in the template(s) using this line:

```
<p><?php the_field('your_field_name', 123); ?></p>
```

The "123" is the page ID of where your content is. It can be found in the URL when you're editing a page/post. Then you only have to edit one page, and it will change on all pages that you wish to display it on.

Plugin Website: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/